# is there any database for Google apps script/workspace add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I am working on a google workspace add-on for gmail. As part of it, I want to store and index some data, so that it can be later aggregated/enriched for insights.
I don't want to use some external(outside-google-workspace) database as it will have data privacy and security implications. So, I want to keep that data within the safe precincts of the user workspace.

Is there any database service within the google workspace for the above mentioned requirements?

PS: I am already aware of Properties service which can store configurations. The data i want to persist is definitely more than that.

Comment: Have you looked into [Google Cloud SQL databases](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#google_cloud_sql_databases)? Would that be an appropriate tool for your purposes?

Comment: @lamblichus I already checked into it. The reservation i have is that it is a different ecosystem than google workspace and it will involve user's data from their google workspace to a google cloud account, which will have security implications.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such database.

The closest alternatives, as already mentioned, are [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service), which has obvious limitations, and [Google Cloud SQL databases](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#google_cloud_sql_databases), which live in Google's cloud but is not part of Google Workspace.